# complex deformations of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety defined over $\mathbf{C}$ (of dimension $>1$) and let $\Theta_A$ be the holomorphic tangent sheaf of $A$.

> **Question.** How does one compute $H^1(A,\Theta_A)$ ?

If $A$ has dimension $1$ then using Serre's duality one finds that 
$H^1(A,\Theta_A)\simeq H^0(A,\omega_A^2)$ where $\omega_A$ is the canonical line bundle of $A$. Since $\omega_A\simeq\mathcal{O}_A$ one finds that 
$h^1(A,\Theta_A)=h^0(A,\mathcal{O}_A)=1$.

Comment: $\Theta_A$ is trivial of rank $g=\dim A$. So it's $H^1$ has dimensional $g^2$. Note that when $g>1$, this is bigger than the dimension of the moduli space of abelian varieties, in case you were wondering that.

Comment: Thanks Donu for the quick answer. So could you give me more details on how you get the $g^2$? 

Comment: So with what you said you need to compute $H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)$

Comment: Hugo, sorry I have to run. The computation of the last thing
should be in Mumford's abelian varieties for example.

Comment: This is also in Kodaira's "Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structures" for general complex tori (not necessarily algebraic). See pages 216-218 for the calculation.

Comment: Of course intuitively I see why we should have $g^2$ since one needs to choose $2g$ $R$-linearly vectors in $C^g$ so we see that the moduli space of $g$-dimensional complex tori should be something like 
$GL_{2g}(Z)\backspace M_{2g\times 2g}(R)/GL_g(C)$ so the complex dimension is $g^2$ but this is just a heuristic. But at the end one needs to invoke something in order to compute the dimension of this $H^1$ since it boils down to solve some system of differential equations.  

Comment: The tangent bundle $\Theta_A$ is trivial of rank $g$, as Donu notes, and so $\dim H^1(A,\Theta_A) = g H^1(A,\mathcal O_A)$.  The fact that $H^1(A,\mathcal A)$ has dimension $g$ is a standard fact.  One way to prove it is by Hodge symmetry: it has the same dimension as $H^0(A,\Omega^1_A)$, and the latter has dimension $g$ because an every holomorphic one-form on an abelian variety is necessarily invariant, and any $g$-dimensional Lie group has a $g$-dimensional space of invariant one-forms.  Regards,

Comment: Typo: "$H^1(A,\mathcal A)$" should read "$H^1(A, \mathcal O_A)$".

Comment: Dear Hugo, Regarding your question about CM abelian varieties: yes, one can see that they are rigid, and hence defined over number fields.    (One way to see it is just in terms of the period lattice.)  This is a standard fact and standard argument; it is ubiquitous in the Shimura variety literature, but I don't know where else it is discussed.  (Perhaps in Shimura and Taniyama's book?)  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: Dear Matthew, so when you say that abelian varieties are rigid do you mean that you are looking for complex deformations that preserve their endomorphism ring? If yes, then how does this fit into classical deformation theory "a la Kodaira-Spencer"? 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hugo,

Although this was already discussed in the comments, perhaps I can write few more details
here. The material can be found in many books such as Mumford's Abelian Varieties or
the book on the same by Birkenhake and Lange.

Claim $\dim H^1(A,\Theta)= g^2$.

The first thing to observe is that $A$ is a group, so a basis for the tangent space
at $0$ can be translated to give a global basis. Thus the tangent bundle 
$\Theta=\mathcal{O}_A^g$ where $g=\dim A$. Thus $H^1(A,\Theta)= H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)^g$.
So this reduces the claim to checking $\dim H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)=g$. For this, let me use
the Hodge theorem (alternatives can be found in the above refs.).
Write $A$ as the
quotient of $\mathbb{C}^g$ by a lattice. The Euclidean metric induces a Kähler metric
on $A$, with respect to which $H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)$ can be realized as the space
of harmonic forms of type $(0,1)$. These are necessarily invariant under the group, because the metric is. $\lbrace d\bar z_1,\ldots, d\bar z_g\rbrace$ give a basis for the invariant $(0,1)$-forms, and they are clearly harmonic. So this proves the claim.

Finally, by Kodaira-Spencer, $H^1(A,\Theta)$ is the space of first order deformations of $A$. As noted above, the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties has
dimension only $g(g+1)/2$. Which means that roughly half these deformations 
are nonalgebraic!

Comment: Thanks Donu, so you are using the Dolbeault's isomorphism $H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)≃H_{\overline{\partial}}^{0,1}(A)$. 

Comment: Donu, Is there a way using (only) deformation theory to see that an abelian variety with complex multiplication can be defined over number field? 

When $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\amthbf{C}$ such that
$H^1(X,\Theta_X)=0$ then since the Kodaira-Spencer map is trivial we see readily that $X$ can be defined over a number field. I know about the classical proof for elliptic curves which uses the $j$-invariant but I'm wondering if there exists some refinement of the deformation theory argument that I have just explained.  

Comment: Hugo: (1) yes, Dolbeault. (2) That's an interesting thought. It seems entirely plausible to me that there should be a deformation theory for varieties with endomorphisms, and that CM abelian vars may be rigid. But I haven't seen such theory/computation worked out.